# Cross compiling drivers for USB modem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I have a physical card with an IMX6 CPU that runs Linux (a kernel I compiled from source, from the manufacturer's website). I also have a USB Cellular modem dongle that I want to use with the card. However, when I plug the dongle in the card, I get this in `dmesg`:

```
[   29.825491] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ci_hdrc
[   29.983396] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   29.991796] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   30.987573] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   30.996027] scsi 0:0:0:1: CD-ROM            ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   31.008487] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

It looks like Linux is recognizing the device as a mass storage device (it doubles as a storage device), but not as a modem. When I insert the same dongle into a regular Ubuntu machine, I get this:

```
[264822.947101] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[264823.086874] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=0017
[264823.086880] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=[REDACTED]
[264823.086883] usb 1-5: Product: HSPA Data Card
[264823.086886] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: USBModem
[264823.086888] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: [REDACTED]
[264823.089483] option 1-5:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[264823.089685] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[264823.089816] option 1-5:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[264823.090019] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[264823.090150] option 1-5:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[264823.090311] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[264823.090433] option 1-5:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[264823.090574] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[264823.090666] usb-storage 1-5:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
[264823.090916] scsi host16: usb-storage 1-5:1.4
[264823.091067] option 1-5:1.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[264823.091133] usb 1-5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
[264824.089843] scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[264824.090238] sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[264824.093552] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I know how to compile modules externally and into the kernel, by choosing them in `menuconfig`. However, I don't know which modules I should compile for this device, if they are even included in the kernel source. How can I find which modules / drivers to compile?

Answer (score 1):

USB modems often start up as Mass storage devices to allow for driver installation.

You can use software such as [USB_ModeSwitch](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/) to force it to change modes. (this is likely already installed and working on your Ubuntu system)

Failing that, many will switch modes when their storage is ejected (as by `eject`).

Comment: It looks like `eject` has no effect at all. I can't even say to where this device is mapped. I found under `/dev/disk/by-id/` somethin called `usb-ALCATEL_Mass_Storage-<SERIAL>` but I have no idea what can I do with that. Any idea?

Comment: @AndyThomas: Given your dmesg output, I expect `eject /dev/sda` should probably work, but using `usb_modeswitch` will probably be easier.

Comment: `eject /dev/sda` has no effect either. I don't have `usb_modeswitch` on my board, do you think it's worth cross compile efforts?

Comment: Probably is, as I'm quite sure that your device exists in its database. I'd say it's probably worth a try.

Comment: OK I found a static arm version here (http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/usb_modeswitch-1.1.9-arm-static.bz2). I put it on the board and it works fine (`./usb_modeswitch -h`) but from there what? how do I get the paramters for: `usb_modeswitch -v <vid of modem>-p <pid of modem> -M  <message to send>`? Thank you mate.

Comment: Get the [usb_modeswitch database](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/usb-modeswitch-data-20160112.tar.bz2), as I understand, with it available you should be able to run `usb_modeswitch -c` and the configuration file matching your VID:PID. Also, if you happen to be using udev, that package includes the relevant rule file.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the sysfs attributes in Ubuntu for the associated driver
in /sys/bus/usb/devices/ and enable that driver in your board kernel configuration.